# Optimise PostgreSQL multi-table search query

Tags: performance, postgresql, search

I have a website with a multi-table search tool, displaying the results with a pagination.

The PostgreSQL tables have tens of thousands rows, and I'd like to improve the performance : if I search for a word (or several), it takes a few seconds, but if I search a single letter (for example "e"), it takes around 20 seconds.

Here is a very simplified database for example purpose:

```
create table DOG
(
    id_dog SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    birth_date TIMESTAMP NULL
);

create table CAT
(
    id_cat SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    birth_date TIMESTAMP NULL
);

create table BIRD
(
    id_bird SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    birth_date TIMESTAMP NULL
);

insert into DOG values (0, 'Rex', '2002-03-05 12:02:06');
insert into DOG values (1, 'Rantanplan', '2002-03-05 12:02:06');
insert into DOG values (2, 'Milou', '2002-03-05 12:02:06');

insert into CAT values (0, 'Grominet', '2002-03-05 12:02:06');
insert into CAT values (1, 'Bella', '2002-03-05 12:02:06');
insert into CAT values (2, 'Molly', '2002-03-05 12:02:06');

insert into BIRD values (0, 'Titi', '2002-03-05 12:02:06');
insert into BIRD values (1, 'Bip-Bip', '2002-03-05 12:02:06');
insert into BIRD values (2, 'Sunny', '2002-03-05 12:02:06');
```

And here is the corresponding simplified request (in the real case I search in more fields and the tables are not that similar) :

```
select *, count(*) over() as count 
from 
(
    (
        select id_dog as id, birth_date as date, name as title, varchar(4) 'DOG' as table
        from DOG d 
        where unaccent(lower(array_to_string(array[d.name, to_char(d.birth_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')], ' ')))
        like '%' || lower(unaccent('a')) || '%' 
    ) 

    union 
    (
        select id_cat as id, birth_date as date, name as title, varchar(4) 'CAT' as table
        from CAT c
        where unaccent(lower(array_to_string(array[c.name, to_char(c.birth_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')], ' '))) 
        like '%' || lower(unaccent('a')) || '%' 
    ) 
    union 
    (
        select id_bird as id, birth_date as date, name as title, varchar(4) 'BIRD' as table
        from BIRD b
        where unaccent(lower(array_to_string(array[b.name, to_char(b.birth_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')], ' '))) 
        like '%' || lower(unaccent('a')) || '%' 
    )
) 
as results order by DATE offset 0 limit 10;
```

Any idea to improve this? Maybe with a left join?

The problem seems to be that I need to count the number of results in order to display my pagination. If I limit the number of results in each sub-select the query runs fast, but I don't get the right results count.

Comment: First trivial improvement: `union` -->> `UNION ALL` Second: `WHERE unaccent(lower(c.name)) LIKE ...` (since the date would never yield an alphabetic character)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Using UNION ALL didn't change anything in my case, but thanks to point it, it's indeed more suited. For the date, searching "a" is just an example, the user may search "2015-03-24"

Comment: like `lower(unaccent('a'))` ? Name and date are separate fields and types for a reason. If you want to search them both, search them both, but don't concatenate them, that would make indexes unusable. ( however, a ts_vector *would* work on concatenated fields)

Comment: Strange datamodel, birds, dogs and cats are all animals, you need a table "animals" and join to this table.

Comment: @joop I concatenate the date because it's simpler, for example a user can search "test january 2015". In the real query I format the date in several formats. It avoids me to parse the search string in order to try to find a date inside (that would slightly improve the performance but it's clearly not the bottleneck for now).

Comment: @FrankHeikens As stated in my post, this is a simplified database written for example purpose. My real database has no cat, dog  or bird table and, as stated, the real tables fields are not similar. I need performance improvements suggestions, not UML advice. Thanks for your time though